# ReactiveList - Check if property of any list item changes

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a `ReactiveList<SomeObject>`.

What is the best way to detect if any item in the list has `SomeObject.SomeProperty` change?

I could subscribe to each `SomeObject.SomeProperty` separately, but I feel like there must be a Better way?

Comment: Fancy explaining the decision to close?

Comment: The reason given is it doesn't have [mcve].

Comment: I'm not asking for debugging help. I'm asking if there's an alternative to 'manually' adding a binding for each object, when I suspect there might be a `WhenAnyObservable` solution. Adding code that uses the technique I want to avoid is surely only adding useless information?!

Comment: Have you read the docs for `ReactiveList<T>`? Specifically, the [Using Change Tracking](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/#using-change-tracking) section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ChangeTrackingEnabled` property to true and subscribe to `ItemChanged`:

```
ReactiveList<SomeObject> rl = new ReactiveList<SomeObject>() { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
rl.ItemChanged.Subscribe(args =>
{
    string changedPropertyName = args.PropertyName;
    SomeObject changedObject = args.Sender;
});
```